# Transfer 90 GB of photos between two Google Drives which are both personal

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive

How do I transfer files between two Google Drives, both personal? By personal I mean that neither is a work or school account.

## The reason

My wife and I used to both be on the 100 GB plan. We’ve run out of space so I upgraded to the 2 TB plan.

We now want to transfer some 90 GB of photos from my wife’s account to mine, so that we can revert her account to the free plan.

I don’t want to pay for the transfer (other than a bit of electricity).

## Kit available

We don’t have a single computer with enough storage to download everything and upload again.

We have a lenovo x240 which still runs sweet but it’s dual boot (Win 10 & Ubuntu) with limited storage and I’d prefer to avoid running long downloads and uploads on it because I like being able to  switch between OSes.

We then have an old banger Acer D250 netbook with Win XP & Debian which runs ok for its age but again has limited storage, maybe some 20 GB spare.

Ideally I’m hoping there’s a Google Script I can run and leave it running on the old netbook for a week or however long it takes.

I keep hearing about free trial accounts with cloud computing providers - I would be happy to try doing this using a VM or similar, but I’d need to assess the learning curve involved.

Comment: It does not appear Google offers any tools to make this possible which means you will have to download the file offline then upload the file.  After the file has been uploaded, the local file can be deleted and the original cloud copy can also be deleted.

Comment: They do offer VMs at Google Cloud – IIRC there is the "Cloud Shell" as well as a free tier for a small VM – with the advantage that they have a _fast_ connection to the rest of Google services; I've heard of people using rclone to migrate data that way.

Answer (score 1):

- Move your files on the source account to a single folder and share it
- Then in the destination account open the shared link then select all items in that folder > right click > Make a copy

After everything was finished copying then you can move the original files to trash

[image: Make a copy]